# CXF: WSDLToService Error : Input binding does not exist in imported contract

Tags: java, cxf

I'm using wsdl2java to generate right wsdl which will be then used to generate java code.

```
wsdl2service -transport soap -e sname -p pname -n jaxb service.wsdl
```

However I get "WSDLToService Error : Input binding does not exist in imported contract" message in response.
What do i miss and how do I specify binding correctly?

Comment: Try remove **-n jaxb**.

Comment: returns: WSDLToService Error : org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.parser.BadUsageException: Missing option: n